# XCode : Keep button disable till filling all text field available

Tags: objective-c, button, if-statement

I want to keep one button disable  till I fill three textfield with numbers.
After Entering the values in the three textfield, then the button will be enable.

I did the following:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
 NSString *Width = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.Width]];
 NSString *Height = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.Height]];
NSString *Length = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.Length]];

if (([Width length] > 0) && ([Height length] > 0) && ([Length length] > 0)) self.saveBarButton.enabled = YES;
else self.saveBarButton.enabled = NO;
return YES;
}
```

When I run the application, even when I put a number in first textfield, the button became enable.
Why this happen as I already put 3 conditions to enable it as it is shown above.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things -

**One**

Because in all three cases this

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.Height]`

resolves to this for a null argument.

`"(null)"`

so the length is 6 when the value is `nil`

**Two**

Your test relies on 3 pieces of information at once which is the contents of the relevant text fields. 
The delegate method only supplies one piece at a time.

One method is to connect your text fields to IBOutlets and read their values after the change occurs.

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *widthTextField;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lengthTextField;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *heightTextField;

...

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textDidChange:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:textField];

}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:textField];


}


-(void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)note {

    self.saveBarButton.enabled = self.widthTextField.length > 0 &&
                                 self.lengthTextField.length > 0 &&
                                 self.heightTextField.length > 0;

}
```

And an irrelevant style point; by convention Objective-C variables are lower-cased to prevent confusion with Class names.